# Excel create unique list from list with duplicates

Tags: excel

Been trying to figure this out for a while and I am struggling. Assume you have an excel sheet as such

```
+----+-------+--------+
| ID | Group | New ID |
+----+-------+--------+
| 10 | A     |        |
| 20 | B     |        |
| 30 | C     |        |
| 22 | B     |        |
| 35 | C     |        |
| 10 | A     |        |
| 11 | A     |        |
| 20 | B     |        |
| 30 | C     |        |
| 10 | A     |        |
+----+-------+--------+
```

Items in Group A need an ID between 10 and 19, B between 20 and 29, C between 30 and 39. The New ID must be unique, but ID's shouldn't be changed unless necessary. So in the above example the first occurrence of A is fine, the second is a duplicate and needs a new ID, but the 3rd one is using 11, so the 2 second A should be assigned 12, the 4th A should then be assigned 13. If possible this should be done all with formulas and no VBA. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In an unused column to the right, put this into the second row and double-click the 'fill handle'.

```
=COUNTIF(B$2:B2, B2)+(CODE(B2)-64)*10-1
```

[image]